# How do you use Rsync's files-from option?

Tags: backup, rsync

So I wanted to rsync a bunch of files from my mac to an external drive and tried this:

```
$ rsync -vv  --files-from=backup.txt  /Volumes/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/2022-12-27-imac-backup/
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
Copyright (C) 1996-2006 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
<http://rsync.samba.org/>
Capabilities: 64-bit files, socketpairs, hard links, symlinks, batchfiles,
              inplace, IPv6, 64-bit system inums, 64-bit internal inums

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.

rsync is a file transfer program capable of efficient remote update
via a fast differencing algorithm.

Usage: rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... DEST
  or   rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... [USER@]HOST:DEST
  or   rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... [USER@]HOST::DEST
  or   rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/DEST
  or   rsync [OPTION]... [USER@]HOST:SRC [DEST]
  or   rsync [OPTION]... [USER@]HOST::SRC [DEST]
  or   rsync [OPTION]... rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/SRC [DEST]
The ':' usages connect via remote shell, while '::' & 'rsync://' usages connect
to an rsync daemon, and require SRC or DEST to start with a module name.

Options
 -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
 -q, --quiet                 suppress non-error messages
....
....
(snip)
....
Use "rsync --daemon --help" to see the daemon-mode command-line options.
Please see the rsync(1) and rsyncd.conf(5) man pages for full documentation.
See http://rsync.samba.org/ for updates, bug reports, and answers
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/aaefcfd1-5c95-11ed-8734-2e32217d8374/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/options.c(1436) [client=2.6.9]
```

So it does not say what wrong, but something did. I guess the format of the file is wrong? But it is not that exotic:

```
$ cat backup.txt 
/Users/carlerik/Downloads/Paragon-31091-PEU_MacInstallUnlock-15.10.485.dmg 
/Users/carlerik/Documents/Øvelser.ptflow
/Users/carlerik/Pictures/syncdir/2019
/Users/carlerik/Pictures/dump
/Users/carlerik/Pictures/dronebilder* 
/Users/carlerik/Pictures/profilbilde
/Users/carlerik/sohf_next-2022_10_18_11_09_03-dump.sql
/Users/carlerik/develop_k8s-2022_10_25_10_56_35-dump.sql
```

Searching for examples is not that fruitful, since no one lists the contents of the *from file*.

```
$ rsync --version
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a source directory; the paths it gets from the "from" file (backup.txt) are treated as relative to that source. It looks like you have absolute paths in the backup.txt file, so you'd specify `/` as the source directory:

```
rsync -vv  --files-from=backup.txt / /Volumes/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/2022-12-27-imac-backup/
#                                  ^ this is the source directory argument
```

You could also specify `/Users/carlerik` as the source directory, and modify backup.txt to specify only the paths within that (e.g. `Documents/Øvelser.ptflow` instead of `/Users/carlerik/Documents/Øvelser.ptflow`).

Note that the `/` at the beginning of paths in the file is ignored. From the man page:

> The filenames that are read from the FILE are all relative to the source dir -- any leading slashes are removed and no ".." references are allowed to go higher than the source dir. For example, take this command:
>
> `rsync -a --files-from=/tmp/foo /usr remote:/backup`
>
> If /tmp/foo contains the string "bin" (or even "/bin"), the /usr/bin directory will be created as /backup/bin on the remote host.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I think I even tried some variation of this without much luck.